# CSS hack to modify html link text?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

Anyone know of a css hack to change the link text in here:

```
<div id = "foo"> <a href="/" rel="bookmark">Long Text for Regular site</a> </div>
```

to this shorter version.

```
<div id = "foo"> <a href="/" rel="bookmark">Shorter Text</a> </div>
```

I was able to add text before or after the link, using `pseudoselectors` but no luck modifying the link text itself.

I'm using a `squarespace` template, so I'm not able to use javascript to do this or generate better html.

Comment: According to this help page, Squarespace allows you to add JavaScript to your page. http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/438262-can-i-add-custom-html-css-and-javascript-

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish something similar to what you're trying to do with with CSS3 `text-overflow` property:

**HTML**

```
<p>The quick brown fox <a href="#" class="truncate">jumped over the lazy</a> dogs.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
P {
    font-size:12pt;
    line-height:12pt;
}

.truncate {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height:11pt;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/LcS7a/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#foo a{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
    word-spacing:-999px;
    letter-spacing: -999px; 
}
#foo a:after{
    content: "New Text";
    visibility: visible;
    word-spacing:normal;
    letter-spacing: normal; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8DK9g/

Answer (score 1):

** Edit **

Just read you can't alter the HTML that is being generated, leaving this here for anyone that may find it useful

** /Edit **

Using Duver Jaramillo's example, I've moved the shortened text onto the a tag using a data- attribute.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/KrwWL/

HTML

```
<div id = "foo">
    <a href="/" rel="bookmark" data-short-text="Shortened Text">Long Text for Regular site</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#foo a{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
    word-spacing:-999px;
    letter-spacing: -999px; 
}
#foo a:after{
    content: attr(data-short-text);
    visibility: visible;
    word-spacing:normal;
    letter-spacing: normal; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but i'm assuming that he can't change its html, in order to use your solution he will need to add the data-short-text attribute in the html, but if he can edit the html, this solution is much better and clean maintaining content separated from styles.

Comment: Yeah I read that part after submitting the answer.  Leaving for any future use or anything